# Display image next to an input field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to diplay two input fields - Phone and Phone extension in a single line in a visualforce page. Next to Phone, i want a help icon, which shows some text on hover. Problem i have is that the icon falls into next line. Can someone give a good way to resolve this? Here is the code being used -

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="{!$Label.ht_contact_information}">  
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="ContactPhoneSectionItem">

         <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.ht_phone}" for="ContactPhone" />
         <apex:outputPanel >
           <apex:inputField id="contactPhone" value="{!htCase.SuppliedPhone}"  styleClass="htCaseInputElement" required="true"/>
           <apex:image value="{!$Resource.HelpIcon}" title="{!$Label.ht_phone_format_help}"/>
         </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="ContactPhoneExtensionSectionItem">
           <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.ht_phone}" for="contactPhoneExtension" />
             <apex:inputField id="contactPhoneExtension" value="{!htCase.Extension__c}"  styleClass="htCaseInputElement" required="true"/>
        /apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And here is the outcome 
[image]

Not sure whats up with the formatting. Its removing first few lines of the code, where i have a pageblock section with 2 columns. Then i have started a pageblockSectionItem for the first phone field. You can see the rest of the code after that.

The help icon should be right next to where first Phone inputfield ends. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Initially i thought its because of width of the inputfield. But seems like thats not the case. Even if i keep it single column, remove the phone extension item, it still falls onto next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like bug in SFDC. If you remove required=true, it is working fine. If it is the case, you need to use styles and class level validations. :(

Cheers!
Shailesh

Comment: Thanks. You are right. If i remove required=true, its fine

Comment: It's not a "bug", exactly; the required bar actually wraps the input element inside another element that presents the red bar. This element behaves as a block element, which causes it to appear in its own line on the block. This is arguably incorrect, as it should remain an inline-block, but that's where we are today. You could probably write a specific enough CSS rule to override the display mode of the required box, but I didn't take the time to do that the last time I had this exact problem.

Comment: You are correct. @user2957592: You can wrap inputfield and image in different divs and assign CSS to them. Like this: `<apex:outputPanel><br>
           <div style="display:inline-block">
                  <apex:inputField id="contactPhone" value="{!Contact.phone}" required="true" /></div>
              <div style="display:inline-block"><img src="/img/alohaSkin/help_grey.png" /> </div>
           </apex:outputPanel>`

Answer (score 0):

At First I thought its because of width of the column. But even if i reduce it to just 1 column, and remove the second column of phone extension, the help icon still falls into next line.

Here's the code, had to remove the starting < for formatting to work here

apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="{!$Label.ht_contact_information}">
                                                  apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="ContactPhoneSectionItem">

```
                                                      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.ht_phone}" for="ContactPhone" />
                                                      <apex:outputPanel >
                                                      <apex:inputField id="contactPhone" value="{!htCase.SuppliedPhone}"  styleClass="htCaseInputElement" required="true"/>
                                                      <apex:image value="{!$Resource.HelpIcon}" title="{!$Label.ht_phone_format_help}"/>
                                                      </apex:outputPanel>
                                              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And here's the result,

[image]

I want that help icon to be inline with the phone inputfield